# Trigger Before Insert Salesforce APEX to Update Field

Tags: apex, trigger

Not sure if my syntax is correct, what I'm trying to achive is updating a text field (`X80_20__c`), where the data is coming from a formula text field (`X80_20_Yes_or_No__c`). The output from the formula field produces a Yes or No value.

This is the Apex trigger I attempted but its not populating the X80_20__c field. Any help would be appreciated or would a Apex Class be better to do in this situation? Also, I'm avoiding in using a workflow trigger or process builder for this.

```
trigger a8020 on Account (before insert,before update) {
    List obj = [SELECT Id,Name,X80_20_Yes_or_No__c,X80_20__c FROM Account WHERE
 (X80_20_Yes_or_No__c = 'Yes' OR X80_20_Yes_or_no__c = 'No') AND
 Outlet_Type__c = 'Home Depot' AND Has_1_2_3x5_DULO__c = 'Yes' ]; 

    for (Account a: obj) {
        string s = a.X80_20_Yes_or_No__c; 
        a.X80_20__c = s;  
    } 

    update obj; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Formula fields are not populated in `before insert` context, so your query is going to return a set of existing Accounts, not the ones being inserted. (This goes double because your query doesn't include any `Id IN` criterion in the `WHERE` clause, so it's running across the whole database).

Additionally, in a `before insert` context, you do not need to perform an update DML to commit changes you make to objects in the trigger.

In this case, since you're iterating over a set that will either be empty or a group of unrelated existing Accounts rather than `Trigger.new`, the overall outcome is that nothing happens to your newly inserted accounts, and you update some existing records in your database.

If you need to pre-populate this field, you may want to simply implement the formula logic in your trigger. You can iterate over `Trigger.new`, access the Account fields directly (no SOQL required), and update your field without needing DML.

Lastly, since `List` (rather than `List<Account>`) is not a valid type in Apex, I don't believe this will compile as written.

Comment: I'm not trying to insert any new records, but update a field located in the Account object. I tried (after update) and that didn't work either.

Comment: I understand you are not inserting objects. Your trigger fires *on insert*, when an Account is inserted, which is one among several issues here.

Comment: FYI you should be able to get the value even before insert if you call `recalculateFormulas()`.